# Dovecot + pam ldap authentication

Tags: ldap, dovecot, pam

Im trying to authenticate my mail virtual user's by dovecot through LDAP but i want to use PAM to do it instead of dovecot-ldap ( wanna use pam_cas module later on ). I setup everything but my problem is that my user's in ldap got uid without domain part, and dovecot try to authenticate users with full domain name. When i set in dovecot configuration :

auth_username_format = %n

Users can login but the problem is that user can login with user@anydomain and that's not what i want to archive.

My dovecot config looks like this :

```
passdb {
  driver = pam
}


userdb {
  driver = ldap
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
}
```

Want to use PAM to authenticate but look for users in ldap.

I tried to put in passdb part :

args = auth_username_format = %u

or

args = username_format=%n

But it did't strip domain from username

Is there any way to strip domain only from auth part ( passdb ) but not from user lookup ( userdb ) ?

Answer (score 0):

set as separate variable auth_username_format and point it to %n value but with brackets. It should looks like that:
auth_username_format = "%n"